# How do I set values to email addresses using 'INSTR'?

Tags: sql

I have a school assignment where I have a list of people with email addresses. There are three types of email addresses: `@gmail.com`, `@yahoo.com`, and `@hotmail.com`. I need to create a column that shows a `'Y'` next to all the @gmail.com and @yahoo.com email addresses, and a `'N'` next to everyone with @hotmail.com.

This is what I have so far: `DECODE(INSTR(mail, LIKE '%gmail.com' AND '&yahoo.com'), 1, 'Y', 'N') c15`

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: Show your entire query

Comment: `I need to create a column ...` - does that mean a calculated column in the database table?

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when INSTR(mail, 'gmail.com') > 0 or  INSTR(mail, 'yahoo.com') > 0
            then 'y'
            else 'n'
       end as c15
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple CASE statement to determine the correct value (y or n),

```
SELECT email, CASE WHEN LIKE '%gmail.com' OR '%yahoo.com' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS result 
FROM Yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing Juergen D's Answer:

```
select case when INSTR(mail, 'gmail.com') > 0 or  INSTR(mail, 'yahoo.com') > 0
        then 'y'
        case when INSTR(mail, 'hotmail.com') > 0
        then 'n'
        else 'n'
   end as c15
```

I believe in explicitely defining, but in the end it is the same answer. Also, if you're expecting to go into a career with IT then do some research and try things out before giving up and asking!